# merge two set of weka instances with different Attribute set

Tags: merge, weka, instances

i need to merge two instances(those are  output  of `StrinToWordVector`)  with different set of attribute but overlapping  and completely different instances in weka .is there any easy way to do it ?(in other word,i have two tfidf matrix with diferent doc and different word (but overlapped) and i want to have a tfidf matrix that is union of all of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InputMappedClassifier`, although there are two other options if you still have your documents in raw format, as discused [here](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mapping-vocabulary-from-train-to-test.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please check if [weka.join](https://github.com/btaranta/weka.join/) could help you, this is an extended `weka.core.Instaces` class with methods like `innerJoin`, `leftJoin`, `fullJoin`, `update` and `union`.